# How to make a optgroup a checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkboxlist

I have the below code which is displaying the list of checkboxes with groups using optgroup. Now my question is, how do I ensure even the group names have the checkboxes, so that a group can be selected at once ?? Please find the screen shot at the bottom.

```
   <select title="Fruits" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" id="fruits" name="fruits[]">
<option selected="selected" label="All" value="">All</option>
<optgroup label="Fruits" class="fruit" value="">
    <option label="apple" value="1">Apple</option>
    <option label="pear" value="2">Pear</option>
    <option label="orange" value="3">Orange</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Berrys" class="berries" value="">
    <option label="strawberry" value="4">Strawberry</option>
    <option label="raspberry" value="5">Raspberry</option>
    <option label="blueberry" value="6">Blueberry</option>
</optgroup>
   </select>
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried.

Comment: not sure I understand. I didn't use any jquery as of now, just want to have the checkboxes for the groups, so that I can select the entire group at once. Can I enable checkboxes for groups using the jquery code ?

Comment: You can add another 'Select All' in each group.